# Is it possible to plot a graph into an image using matlab (or something else)?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot

I have a picture file of a building (.png) that is in grayscale, and I have a script that generates a grid plot with color intensity of what section of the building someone spent time in during the day. The building is divided into a 3x3 grid and the plot corresponds accordingly. How can I plot this INTO the grayscale image and colorize it so that it matches the 3x3 plot? I have treid to follow this overlay technique but keep getting errors: http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/

My grid plot script:

```
Data = [1:1:9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

M = zeros(3,3);

 for ii = 2:size(Data,1)
      plot(ii-1)
      M(1:end) = Data(ii,:);
      imagesc(M)
      colormap jet
      shading flat %for an exact result
      % shading interp %for a smooth result 
figure
  end
```

Any ideas or is this just not possible? I do have the image processing toolbox and if there is another program better suited for this I am happy to give it a shot.

Edit:

Here is the code I am trying to work with to get the blog post on transparency working:

```
BaseImage = imread('buildinglayout.png'); 
imshow(BaseImage, 'InitialMag', 'fit');
GridPlot = imread('5.png'); %output of grid plot generating script
imshow(GridPlot,'InitialMag','fit')
M(1:end) = Data(ii,:);
h = imshow(M);
hold off
set(h,'AlphaData', GridPlot);
```

And the error I get, though I am willing to bet I am not outlining the overlay properly at all regardless of this error:

```
Error using set
Bad property value found.
Object Name :  image
Property Name :  'AlphaData'.

Error in OverlayPlots (line 13)
set(h,'AlphaData', GridPlot);
```

Comment: What is your error ? Give us this part of the code too.

Comment: @obchardon edited the post to have the error and my attempt at adapting the blog post code.

Comment: AlphaData should be of the same size as CData for your image, that is what set is complaining about.

Comment: @RandomGuy how do I make sure that the size of the grid plot is the same as the size of the building layout? The grid is a 3x3 rectangle, but the building png is an irregular shape. with the image processing toolbox I can do an edge detection and isolate just the building portion, and get those bounds but how do I plot into that space directly?

Comment: could imfilll or just the fill functions work here? http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html

Comment: you should probably resize your image to fit with the dimension of the building image: `imresize(GridPlot,[size(BaseImage,1),size(BaseImage,1)])`

Comment: @obchardon tried that and I get an error bad property value found, object name: image, property name, alpha data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the GridPlot, **without** using figure, is a little tricky.
The following code creates the color plot in the size of your image.
I assumed size is 481 rows and 585 columns.

I created a color map, based on Matlab "JET" color map.
I used an inner loop iterates columns, and outer loop iterates rows.
Each inner iteration fills 1/9 of GridPlot with selected color from the map.

Matalb code:

```
%BuildGridPlot
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
width = 585;  %Number of columns.
height = 481; %Number of rows.

%Fill matrix GridPlot with zeros.
%GridPlot dimensions is: height x width x 3
GridPlot = uint8(zeros(height, width, 3));

w_div3 = width/3;
h_div3 = height/3;

%Create JET color map - each row index is [R, G, B] triple.
ColorMap = jet(9); %Create 9 triples.

%Convert color map from double to uint8.
ColorMap = uint8(round(ColorMap*255));

color_counter = 1;

%Fill 3x3 blocks with different colors.
for y = 0:2
    y0 = 1 + round(y*h_div3);
    y1 = round((y+1)*h_div3);
    y1 = min(y1, height);      %Limit y1 to height (just in case rounded up...).
    for x = 0:2
        x0 = 1 + round(x*w_div3);
        x1 = round((x+1)*w_div3);
        x1 = min(x1, width);   %Limit x1 to width (just in case rounded up...).

        %Fill rectangular area from row y0 to row y1, and from column x0 to
        %column x1 with [R, G, B] triple from ColorMap.
        %The row index of the [R, G, B] triple is color_counter.
        GridPlot(y0:y1, x0:x1, 1) = ColorMap(color_counter, 1); %Set pixels red color
        GridPlot(y0:y1, x0:x1, 2) = ColorMap(color_counter, 2); %Set pixels green color
        GridPlot(y0:y1, x0:x1, 3) = ColorMap(color_counter, 3); %Set pixels blue color

        color_counter = color_counter + 1;
    end
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%GridPlot = imwrite('GridPlot.png');

%Load cameraman as an example for grayscale image.
BaseImage = imread('cameraman.tif');

%Resize BaseImage to [height, width] (simulate size of your image).
BaseImage = imresize(BaseImage, [height, width]);

%Verify 
if (ndims(BaseImage) == 2)
    %Duplicate BaseImage 3 times - convert to RGB.
    BaseImageRGB = cat(3, BaseImage, BaseImage, BaseImage);    
elseif (ndims(BaseImage) == 3)
    %BaseImage is already in RGB format - copy as is.
    BaseImageRGB = BaseImage;    
else
    error('Error: BaseImage is not a valid image');
end

alpha = 0.7; %Tranceparency coefficient.

%Take 70% of BaseImage and 30% of GridPlot image.
BlendedImage = alpha*double(BaseImageRGB) + (1-alpha)*double(GridPlot);

%Convert to uint8 with rounding.
BlendedImage = uint8(round(BlendedImage));

figure;
imshow(BlendedImage);

imwrite(BlendedImage, 'BlendedImage.png');
```

GridPlot:
[image]

BlendedImage:
[image]

Comment: interesting I will give it a shot, what happens if the image is not square? will it fit the grid to the picture?

Comment: does the grid plot creation get it's data from somewhere? or should I generate a bunch of gridplots with my data, save them as pictures, then run the overlay script?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if may answer is exactly what you have meant...
The easiest solution (for me), is working with RGB matrices directly.
In Matlab, RGB image can be represented as 3-dimensional array of uint8 elements.

- RGB(:,:,1) red color plain
- RGB(:,:,2) green color plain
- RGB(:,:,3) blue color plain

Grayscale image can be represented as 1-dimensional array of uint8 elements.

Converting gray scale image to RGB is simple: duplicate the Grayscale matrix three times. I used cat(3, Im, Im, Im).

Blend two RGB images is simple math:
BlendRGB = alpha*RGB1 + (1-alpha)*RGB2.
When alpha is in range [0, 1].
(assume RGB1, RGB2 are the same size and of class double - not uint8).

I used imresize() to make GridPlot the same size (same resolution) as BaseImage.

In my code sample, I converted the figure to GridPlot, and left the gray borders and grid numbers - I assume you have removed it in your '5.png' imgae.

Here is my code sample (based on your original code):

```
Data = [1:1:9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

M = zeros(3,3);
h = figure;
for ii = 2:size(Data,1)
    plot(ii-1)
    M(1:end) = Data(ii,:);
    imagesc(M)
    colormap jet
    shading flat %for an exact result
    % shading interp %for a smooth result 
%figure
end

%Convert figure to RGB image.
GridPlot = frame2im(getframe(h));

%BaseImage = imread('buildinglayout.png');

%Load cameraman as an example for grayscale image.
BaseImage = imread('cameraman.tif');

%GridPlot = imread('5.png'); %output of grid plot generating script

%Resize GridPlot image to be the same dimensions as BaseImage.
GridPlot = imresize(GridPlot, [size(BaseImage, 1), size(BaseImage, 2)]);

%Verify 
if (ndims(BaseImage) == 2)
    %Duplicate BaseImage 3 times - convert to RGB.
    BaseImageRGB = cat(3, BaseImage, BaseImage, BaseImage);    
elseif (ndims(BaseImage) == 3)
    %BaseImage is already in RGB format - copy as is.
    BaseImageRGB = BaseImage;    
else
    error('Error: BaseImage is not a valid image');
end

alpha = 0.7; %Tranceparency coefficient.

%Take 70% of BaseImage and 30% of GridPlot image.
BlendedImage = alpha*double(BaseImageRGB) + (1-alpha)*double(GridPlot);

%Convert to uint8 with rounding.
BlendedImage = uint8(round(BlendedImage));

figure;
imshow(BlendedImage);

imwrite(BlendedImage, 'BlendedImage.png');
```

BlendedImage:
[image]

Comment: That looks like a great start for me, thank you!! But I am getting an error: Error using iptcheckmap (line 35)
Function IMRESIZE expected input number 2, MAP, to be a valid colormap. Valid
colormaps cannot have values outside the range [0,1].

Comment: imresize can used: B = imresize(A, scale) or B = imresize(A, [numrows numcols]).

Comment: if I try the GridPlot= imresize(GridPlot, [481 585] line I get an error further down during the blending: Array dimensions must match for binary array op.

Error in Plots (line 36)
BlendedImage = alpha*double(BaseImageRGB) + (1-alpha)*double(GridPlot);

Comment: I modified the code sample to be a bit more tolerative.

Comment: That works great! now to figure out how to get it to plot in just the area of my picture. in your case how would I plot in just the man in your photo?