# How do I superimpose two images in MATLAB with a specified transparency?

Tags: matlab

I get two images from input and also an opacity value between 0 and 1 from input, then make the second image transparent according to the opacity value, and finally combine the two images. If A is the first image and B is the second image, then C should contain the combined/supreimposed images.
I have used this:

```
A=imread('img1.jpg');
B=imread('img4.jpg');
imshow(A);
hold on;
h=imshow(B);
set(h,'Alphadata',0.6);
```

This only shows the output, but I want to have the output in C.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172389/how-do-i-make-a-png-with-transparency-appear-transparent-in-matlab?

Comment: @Ali Rokni That didn't work. My pictures are RGB.

Comment: @AZ009 why does not the following suit you?
`im1 = imread('s1.jpg');`
`im2 = imread('s2.jpg');`
`imshow(0.7*im1 + 0.3*im2)`

Comment: You can use C = 0.4*A + 0.6*B. Link to my related post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224271/is-it-possible-to-plot-a-graph-into-an-image-using-matlab-or-something-else/38249901#38249901). I think the right term is **"Alpha Blending"**